# Laravel cookies not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-5.3

I want to store cookies in my browser for some later use. my code is working fine in chrome but when i check it in Internet explorer my cookies not working.k

```
$cookie_data['string']=$refral_string;
$cookie_data['counter']=1;
$cookie = Cookie::queue('cookie_data',$cookie_data);

if(Cookie::get('cookie_data')) {
    $cookies_data=Cookie::get('cookie_data');
    $cookies_data['counter'];
    $string =  $cookies_data['string'];
    $refral = Refral::where('refral_string','=',$string)->first();

    if($cookies_data['counter'] < 3) {

        $data = new Visitor();
        $data->refral_id = $refral->id;
        $data->visitor_id = $user->id;
        $data->save();
        $cookie_data=array();
        $cookies_data['string']=$refral->refral_string;
        $cookies_data['counter']=$cookies_data['counter']+1;
        $cookie = Cookie::queue('cookie_data',$cookies_data);

    }
}
```

When I check this in my blade file it is working in chrome giving me out put but not working in internet explorer.

Comment: Have you checked that you've enabled cookies on Internet Explorer http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-enable-cookies-internet-explorer

Comment: yes i have checked i have enabled cookies but not working.